# Typescript: Insert a variable before a matched string

Tags: javascript, json, regex, typescript

```
getAnArticle(articleId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(`${this._url}/${articleId}`)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .do(value => console.log(value))
      .catch((error) => Observable.throw(error));
  }
```

In the above code, the http.get is requesting from a URL as follows:

```
http://website.com/.json/5
```

How can I insert the `{articleId}` (5 in this example) before the .json so the URL is actually read as:

```
http://website.com/5.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `this._url` variable is pretty broken. The correct way to achieve this would be to fix your variable so that it is more easy to manipulate. If you cannot modify the way this variable is calculated your only chance is to replace the value:

```
return this._http.get(this._url.replace(".json", articleId + ".json"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this (supposing your url has already the `.json`)

```js
var url = 'www.asd.com/.json'
var articleId = 2;
var a = `${url.split('/.json')[0]}/${articleId}.json`
console.log(a)
```

In your case:

```
getAnArticle(articleId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(`${this._url.split('/.json')[0]}/${articleId}.json`)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .do(value => console.log(value))
      .catch((error) => Observable.throw(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of `this.url` you could define it with a token to indicate where the id should go e.g.

```
this._url = 'http://website.com/{articleId}.json';
...
return this._http.get('${this._url.replace('{id}', articleId))
```

That way your code isn't coupled to the url format.